# Tizen Active Security Profile Not Set

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-install

I am getting Tizen Security Profile Not set while running an application on Emulator. How to Fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The above error can be resolved by looking at the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4OIWT9KiF40. Thanks to the Video Poster.

Or Follow below Steps :-

1. Click on popup Security Profile.
2. Click on Generate. Give any value for key fileName, Alias, Password. Remaining field are not mandatory.
3. Click ok -> yes. Then Apply -> ok.

Comment: YouTube videos by themselves don't constitute an answer.  Unless you can give the solution in words, you can just delete this question.

Comment: Added Description. Thanks for your Comment.